# MapView causes error on IOS using expo but only if the map is present when initially building the app

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I have code to display a map with the users location and pins of other users around them in a certain radius. It works perfectly fine on android but for some reason on IOS I am getting an error "exception thrown while executing a ui block." The wierd thing is that if I delete the MapView component and let it load nothing, then put the MapView component back it works fine on refresh, it seems to only break if it has to do the initial build with the MapView.

Here is the map view component:

```
      {/* Render map using Google Maps API */}
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        // Show users location, disable scroll, rotate, and zoom permissions to lock map at users location
        onMapReady={() => {
          setShowLocation(true);
          setAllowScroll(false);
        }}
        showsUserLocation={showLocation}
        scrollEnabled={allowScroll}
        rotateEnabled={allowScroll}
        zoomEnabled={allowScroll}
        //Set region based on user current location, delta is set to show a roughly 5km square
        region={{
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: long,
          latitudeDelta: 0.09,
          longitudeDelta: 0.09,
        }}
      >
        {/* Generate markers based on array of nearby users */}
        {nearbyUsers[0] != null &&
          nearbyUsers.map((marker, index) => (
            <Marker
              key={index}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: marker.latitude,
                longitude: marker.longitude,
              }}
              title={marker.id}
            />
          ))}
        {/* Display a 5km radius circle around users location to show area of potential matches */}
        {lat != null && long != null ? (
          <Circle
            center={{ latitude: lat, longitude: long }}
            radius={5000}
            strokeWidth={1}
            strokeColor={"#1a66ff"}
            fillColor={"rgba(230,238,255,0.5)"}
          />
        ) : null}
      </MapView>
```

And in case it's needed here is my full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Application from "expo-application";
import { getDistance } from "geolib";
import { db } from "./Firestore";
import { setDoc, doc, collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import MapView, { Circle, Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";

export default function App() {
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
  const [long, setLong] = useState(null);
  const [nearbyUsers, setNearbyUsers] = useState([]);
  const [allowScroll, setAllowScroll] = useState(true);
  const [showLocation, setShowLocation] = useState(false);
  let deviceID;
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      //Await location permission
      await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      //Get location
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      //Set lat and long states
      setLat(location.coords.latitude);
      setLong(location.coords.longitude);
      //Save location to firebase under a unique device ID
      if (Platform.OS == "android") {
        deviceID = Application.androidId;
      }
      if (Platform.OS == "ios") {
        deviceID = await Application.getIosIdForVendorAsync();
      }
      try {
        await setDoc(doc(db, "Locations", deviceID), {
          lat: location.coords.latitude,
          long: location.coords.longitude,
        });
        console.log("Document written");
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
      }
      //Get all other user locations and check if they are within 5km
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Locations"));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if (doc.id != deviceID) {
          if (
            getDistance(
              {
                latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                longitude: location.coords.longitude,
              },
              {
                latitude: doc.data().lat,
                longitude: doc.data().long,
              }
            ) < 5000
          ) {
            const user = {
              id: doc.id,
              latitude: doc.data().lat,
              longitude: doc.data().long,
            };
            //Populate an array with all in range users as determined above
            setNearbyUsers((current) => [...current, user]);
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Render map using Google Maps API */}
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        // Show users location, disable scroll, rotate, and zoom permissions to lock map at users location
        onMapReady={() => {
          setShowLocation(true);
          setAllowScroll(false);
        }}
        showsUserLocation={showLocation}
        scrollEnabled={allowScroll}
        rotateEnabled={allowScroll}
        zoomEnabled={allowScroll}
        //Set region based on user current location, delta is set to show a roughly 5km square
        region={{
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: long,
          latitudeDelta: 0.09,
          longitudeDelta: 0.09,
        }}
      >
        {/* Generate markers based on array of nearby users */}
        {nearbyUsers[0] != null &&
          nearbyUsers.map((marker, index) => (
            <Marker
              key={index}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: marker.latitude,
                longitude: marker.longitude,
              }}
              title={marker.id}
            />
          ))}
        {/* Display a 5km radius circle around users location to show area of potential matches */}
        {lat != null && long != null ? (
          <Circle
            center={{ latitude: lat, longitude: long }}
            radius={5000}
            strokeWidth={1}
            strokeColor={"#1a66ff"}
            fillColor={"rgba(230,238,255,0.5)"}
          />
        ) : null}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}

// Basic styling to center map and have it be the correct size for 5km circle
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  map: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "47.5%",
  },
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue? I am on Expo SDK 48 managed. In my case "PROVIDER_GOOGLE" is not working. I get apple map.